# Oh No. I had those today

Tags: word, knowledge, wordplay

> Who?
>
> That miserable,
>
> Sick man
>
> Was poisoned?

Eleven letter word

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Today, I think you had

> **quesadillas**  - tortillas filled with cheese and perhaps meats and spices.

Who? That

> **que** is Spanish for Who?/That

miserable

> **sad**

Sick man.

> **ill**

Was poisoned?

> **As** is the chemical symbol for Arsenic - credit @Stiv

Comment: Neat :) The OP may be referring to rot13(Nf orvat gur purzvpny flzoby sbe Nefravp)

Comment: Thank you Stiv - that's much better!

Comment: That is exactly what I was thinking @Stiv